# How can I convert an object from a combobox selected item to a string

Tags: c#, winforms

This is all in a WINDOWS FORM C#, MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 2008

I have a combo box that is being displayed this way:

```
private void populateCombos()
    {
        string GetConn1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\Data\\Db\\Comp.mdb";
        string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT DC FROM Comp";
        OleDbDataAdapter dA = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, GetConn1);
        DataTable dC = new DataTable();
        dA.Fill(dC);
        comboBoxDC.DataSource = dC;
        comboBoxDC.DisplayMember = "DC";

        string GetConn2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\Data\\Db\\Comp.mdb";
        string queryString2 = "SELECT DISTINCT PL FROM Comp";
        OleDbDataAdapter dA2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString2, GetConn2);
        DataTable pL = new DataTable();
        dA2.Fill(pL);
        comboBoxPL.DataSource = pL;
        comboBoxPL.DisplayMember = "PL";
    }
```

I am having issues here being that I cannot make the selected item into a string:

```
        object da = comboBoxDC.SelectedItem;
        object pr = comboBoxPL.SelectedItem;
        Console.WriteLine(da.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(da);
        Console.WriteLine(pr);
        //Connection...

        var list = new List<dataQuery>();
        string GetConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\Data\\Db\\Comp.mdb";
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString;
        string queryString = "SELECT DC, PL, CompID, User, Email FROM Comp WHERE DC = \'" + da + "\' AND PL = \'" + pr + "\'";
```

And in order for me to query these commands I need the selected item comboBoxDC to be a string and same for comboBoxPL.

ANSWER!!!!!!!:

So I found this out:

code:

```
string da = comboBoxDC.Text.ToString();

string pr = comboBoxPL.Text.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(da)

Console.WriteLine(pr)
```

output is successful with text.tostring and is actually string.

Comment: Why does `comboBoxDC.SelectedItem.ToString()` not cut it?

Comment: Is this for WinForms, WPF or ASP.Net?

Comment: @Bobby, While funny and extremely relevant, it's not immediately clear what you're linking to. ;)

Comment: @J. Steen: True...but my 5-Minute grace-period is over. :( But at least the first past hints at it. ;)

Comment: @Bobby, Upvoted anyway. Always loved the comic strip.

Comment: @Sean.  Please see my solution below and mark it as the answer or comment on the results of the modifications.  Thank you :)

Comment: That's not the solution.  The displayed text is dynamic and can change.  I've never been able to get consistent results by pulling the text directly.  Part of the problem is that the text can change depending on what the user types.  Play around with it and see what happens.  Depending on your setup, this may suffice, but I'd still recommend trying to convert the "SelectedValue" object to a string.  Also see this MSDN documentation on getting/setting the text value. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBoxDC.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Works fine on my WPF solutions.

Answer (score 2):

you need to cast selecteditem into particular class and then to string.
in this case you have binded datatable with combobox so cast in this way.

```
String str = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [toString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx#Y456) method on the SelectedItem. From MSDN,

```
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: That should be happening anyway when you concatenate an object with a string, ToString() is called automatically.  Though I don't understand why it's not working in the original problem.

Comment: It shows System.Data.DataRowView for  `Object da = comboBoxDC.SelectedItem;` and `Console.WriteLine(da.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in WinForms, my guess is that when you call comboBoxDC.SelectedItem the result is "System.Data.DataRowView".  The problem with your code is that you only set the DisplayMember.  If you do not set the ValueMember property, the default value of the ComboBox selection is a DataRowView, if your data source is a DataTable (or DataView).

To get the data you are looking for, modify your code like the example below.

**EDIT**
Apologies, my method would work, assuming that your fields are Text Objects. If they are not (i.e. Decimals, Ints, etc.) you will need to first cast them to their respective data types, and then call ToString() on the result.

If you set the ValueMember for a field within your data object, it will not be a DataRowView, but the field specified.  If you are still getting "System.Data.DataRowView" as the string result, then there is another error with your code.  Please update your question and I'll help you find it.

```
    private void populateCombos()
    {
    string GetConn1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\Data\\Db\\Comp.mdb";
    string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT DC FROM Comp";
    OleDbDataAdapter dA = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, GetConn1);
    DataTable dC = new DataTable();
    dA.Fill(dC);
    comboBoxDC.DataSource = dC;
    comboBoxDC.DisplayMember = "DC";
    comboBoxDC.ValueMember = "DC"; //Add this line.

    string GetConn2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\\Data\\Db\\Comp.mdb";
    string queryString2 = "SELECT DISTINCT PL FROM Comp";
    OleDbDataAdapter dA2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString2, GetConn2);
    DataTable pL = new DataTable();
    dA2.Fill(pL);
    comboBoxPL.DataSource = pL;
    comboBoxPL.DisplayMember = "PL";
    comboBoxPL.ValueMember = "PL"; //Add this line, too.
}
```

Now, change your code that gets the text value as follows:

```
    string sDa = comboBoxDC.SelectedValue.ToString(); //Do this if this is a string column
    string sPr = comboBoxPL.SelectedValue.ToString(); // ''   ''    ''   ''   ''

    //If your data is not strings, cast them to their respective types

    Console.WriteLine(da.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(sDa);
    Console.WriteLine(sPr);
```

Comment: It is still showing `System.Data.DataRowView` for `string da = comboBoxDC.SelectedItem.ToString;` and `Console.WriteLine(da);` and also pr respectively. I am not sure as to why System.Data.DataRowView is showing here.

Comment: @Sean Shydow, because when you call .ToString() on some objects, they will default to Object.ToString() which simply returns the name of the type.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out above. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

SelectedItem is exposed as a string but you've cast it to an object. Try replacing the assignment with:

```
string da = comboBoxDC.SelectedItem;
string pr = comboBoxPL.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: [No, it's not, not in my book.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx)

Comment: If this is a WinForms ComboBox, the SelectedItem property has type object, and this code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yea I have tried that and I get this error.          Error 1: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I've been stuck doing web dev so long I immediately assumed that was what the question was for! As advised, change the querystring components from 'da' and pr to 'da.ToString()' and 'pr.ToString' respectively.

Comment: @Sean Shydow, also, as asked and hinted at several times - add tags as to WHICH UI framework you're coding in, when you ask questions that are specific to what UI framework you use. =)

Comment: Windows form, Microsoft Visual 2008