# winforms combobox c# 3 values

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have been looking to some posts about comboboxes, but couldn't find a fitting answer on my question.

Im having an issue with the following scenario:
I have a list of objects, taxrates, that is retrieved of the database. Every taxrate has an ID, a coefficient, a short description and a longdescription. 
On my productview i made a combobox so the user can choose the taxrate.

Now the issue. I have basicly 3 things i need from the combobox: ID (to the id in my productstable), short description(to make it readable for my user) and coefficient(to calculate the price exVat). 
But i can only choose "Displaymember" and "Valuemember". So in this case im kind of stuck, because i have no idea what the solution for this is.

The code (the view):

```
 private void ProductView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cbVatCodes.DataSource = productPresenter.getTaxRates();
        cbVatCodes.DisplayMember = "taxCodeShortDescr";
        cbVatCodes.ValueMember = "taxCoefficient";
        rdonew_CheckedChanged(null, null);
    }

  private void cbVatCodes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productPresenter.calculateVat(Convert.ToDecimal(txtPriceExVat.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Convert.ToDecimal(cbVatCodes.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
```

The presenter:

```
  public List<tbl_taxCodes> getTaxRates()
     {
         using (var products = new DBCrownfishEntities())
         {
             var taxRates = from t in products.tbl_taxCodes
                           select t;

             return taxRates.ToList();
         }
     }` public void addProduct(string productCode, string productName, string productDescription, decimal priceExVat, decimal priceIncVat, string serialNumber, bool isService)
     {
         tbl_products product = new tbl_products();
         product.ProductCode = productCode;
         product.ProductName = productName;
         product.ProductDescription = productDescription;
         product.ProductPriceExVat = priceExVat;
         product.ProductPriceInclVat = priceIncVat;
         product.ProductSerialNumber = serialNumber;
         product.IsService = isService;}`
```

As you can see, at this moment i am not able to retrieve the taxrateID because i can only get 2 values (selectedvalue and selectedtext)

Comment: If you bound the cbo to the datatable and use the ID as the value member, you could fetch whatever you want back using the SelectedValue

Comment: bind your ID (ValueMember) and Description  (DispalyMember); have a list of your pre-defined values retrieved temporarily; when user makes a selection get the object necessary from temp storage proably session and use that object parameters for other tasks

Comment: Would you consider adding to the `.Items` collection of your combobox rather than using the `.DataSource` property? If so then you can just cast the `.SelectedItem` to your object and access its properties that way. EDIT: I found out that you still can cast the `.SelectedItem` from a datasource populated combobox, although it is a bit more complex. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844724/how-can-i-convert-an-object-from-a-combobox-selected-item-to-a-string

Comment: As @UpAllNight stated, you can cast `SelectedItem `property of `ComboBox` to `tbl_taxCodes`, then use it. Example: `tbl_taxCodes temp = (tbl_taxCodes)cbVatCodes.SelectedItem;` . Before using, remember to check `temp` and make sure it is not `null`.

Comment: Ah, yeah ofcourse. Basicly the same procedure as this?:  
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtProductCode.Text = ((tbl_products)cbProducts.SelectedItem).ProductCode.ToString();
            txtProductName.Text = ((tbl_products)cbProducts.SelectedItem).ProductName.ToString();

Comment: @Kevin Yes, a little ugly but will do the job.

Comment: @Kevin I'd suggest creating a variable for the current item in the event handler: `var currentItem = cbProducts.SelectedItem as tbl_products;` then you can access its properties in a bit nicer form: `txtProductCode.Text = currentItem.ProductCode.ToString();`

Comment: @Gabor, thanks! Thats more readable indeed! Going to edit the rest of the castings also to this way.